# Communicate with a subprocess using pyzmq

Tags: python, multiprocessing, zeromq

I'm trying to communicate with a subprocess which I start using `multiprocessing.Process` via a ZeroMQ socket.  I know that there exist solutions to communicate with subprocesses within the `multiprocessing` module but I want to ultimately communicate with a function from a shared library written in C++.  Without further ado, here is the self-contained code:

```
import time
import zmq
import multiprocessing

def perform(nseconds, endpoint):
    context = zmq.Context()
    publisher = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
    publisher.connect(endpoint)

    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(nseconds)
        publisher.send_string("{}".format(i))
    publisher.send_string(">>END")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    socket.bind("tcp://*:*")
    socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, u"")
    endpoint = socket.getsockopt_string(zmq.LAST_ENDPOINT)

    print("Binding via {}".format(endpoint))

    t = multiprocessing.Process(target=perform, args=(1,endpoint))
    t.start()

    string = ""
    while not ">>END" in string:
        string = socket.recv_string()
        print(string)

    t.join()
```

This code runs perfectly fine on GNU/Linux with the expected output:

```
Binding via tcp://0.0.0.0:34149
0
1
2
3
4
>>END
```

But running this on Windows with Python from Anaconda and `pyzmq` version 16.0.2 installed with `conda install pyzmq` it crashes with the following error:

```
Binding via tcp://0.0.0.0:52019
Assertion failed: Can't assign requested address (bundled\zeromq\src\tcp_connect
er.cpp:341)
```

How do I fix this?  Or am I doing it wrong?  And if I am doing it wrong, why is it platform dependent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Remove the wildcard in `socket.bind( "tcp://*:*" )`

First,
this is very platform specific, one ought never rely on how the wildcard expansion will get handled on unknown ecosystem details in production. Be explicit.

Next,
this is on the very contrary to the concise, state-of-art resources management practice in Distributed-systems design and there could be hardly a worse idea from the architecture point of view, than to `.bind()` straight on all ports on all `localhost` available addresses. Just imagine what this causes inside the `Context()`-instance, to manage all that herd of endpoints and their associated resources' pools ready and sniffing for a potentially incoming connection request ( just in case one such may appear ). No.

Never do this.

---

### Performance [sins and other aspects  <sub>- ref. my criticism on Amdahl's Law v/s costs</sub>](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3)

Well, having seen your publications, I will not expand this a lot, but yet have to add, the Distributed-computing realm requires a lot of care spent on details -- never expect a few SLOCs to perform any good for HPC computations.

**The worst sins come from a good will to improve some process**. If a code spins-off a process ( what the **`multiprocessing`** is exactly designed to do ), not many people also associate with such a SLOC the actual costs, that have to be paid, before the departed code gets it's first chance to start processing ( replica of the complete python execution environment ( so as to escape from the original local-GIL etc ) -- so your code has to pay in both **`[TIME]`** and **`[SPACE]`** for a huge memory-to-memory transfer, next your proposed code instantiates another "remote"-process **`Context()`**-engine. While this may look smart, your code has to pay for it again all costs - and spend just a few SLOCs to process. Next, always use rather a **`.setsockopt(  zmq.LINGER, 0 )`**, so as not to leave your resources infinitely blocking a graceful termination. While this seems as a "nice-to-have" preventive step, it is rather a "must-do" lifesaver, before hunting "what went wrong this time?" on a big and expensive computing infrastructure...

Many other performance tweaking deserves to be done **before** shelling out **`multiprocessing.Process( ... )`**, which goes way beyond the scope of this post. But worth mastering, definitely before running many-times inefficient code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!  One minor thing though, `tcp://127.0.0.1:*` binds a system-assigned port and not *all* ports, like you suggest in the answer.  In my case the cost of spinning up the subprocess is very much negligible to the cost of computation being done in it, but nevertheless, thank you for your additional performance tips.

Comment: Being a rather old dog on this to learn *new tricks*, I have principally never recommended to use wildcards since API v.2.x ( where none such option was even thinkable for the port# ) and will not change this practice ( as many dependencies out-of-one's domain of control get worse and worse >>> http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-tcp ). If your "computation"-payload is overhead-aware Amdahl's Law re-formulation safe, yet worth to know about performance tweaking options the Context()-I/O-datapumps will benefit from. Check the API (+ rather do not use the newest thread-safe promises ( until proven ) )

Comment: By using the wildcard I basically only avoid having to write a loop over a range of ports in case I can't bind to the first one.  I'm only using Python for visualization of my data and the C++ shared library is doing all the heavy lifting, so `multiprocessing` is only there to spawn the main computation loop from the library in an extra process, so I can update the plot while the numbers are being crunched.

Comment: Even Cray Chapel uses ZeroMQ for allowing HPC assemblies of heterogeneous non-uniform distributed-processing, so, if your [CPU_core*hours] rather go into the HPC / cluster-processing direction, you may easily integrate the highest power number-crunching facilities independently from the python and yet enjoy tools of choice on your front-end GUI. Anyway, **good hunt for the quantum wires** using smart numerical solutions!